# Is there a way to pull a value from a cell or range of cells on Sheet1 and put it in the left footer, and set font color for the footer?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been unable to successfully set the font attributes while pulling a range of cells from one sheet and setting those values as the header/footer for the entire workbook.

I have a 90- or so page workbook, and want to pull the range of cells from one sheet into the header for the entire workbook, but I also want to set font color, etc. I have tried referring to a single cell, a range of cells, and referring to a function but nothing seems to work.
Here is my code so far, with comments that will hopefully help:

```
Sub InsertHeaderFooter()
PURPOSE: Insert Image File into Spreadsheet Header or Footer on every selected worksheet
SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault(Modified by FiveLetterIan)


Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ImgPath As String

'*** Call Function for Left footer
Dim LFRange As Range
Set LFRange = Worksheets("SetupPrint").Range("B3:C3")
Dim LFRange2 As Range
Set LFRange2 = Worksheets("SetupPrint").Range("B7:C7")
Dim leftFooter As String
leftFooter = lowerleft(LFRange) & lowerleft(LFRange2)

'*** Call Function for Right Footer
Dim RFRange As Range
Set RFRange = Worksheets("SetupPrint").Range("B11:C11")
Dim rightFooter As String
rightFooter = lowerleft(RFRange)

'Image Location
ImgPath = "c:\desktop\image.jpg"
'Does the Image File Exist?
On Error Resume Next
    Validation = Dir(ImgPath)
On Error GoTo 0

If Validation = "" Then
    MsgBox "Could not locate image file from:" & ImgPath
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                   With WS.PageSetup
                                       .LeftHeader = "LEFTHEADERTEXT"
                                       .RightHeaderPicture.Filename = ImgPath
                                            .Zoom = False
                                            .FitToPagesTall = False
                                            .FitToPagesWide = 1
                                       .leftFooter = leftFooter
                                       .rightFooter = rightFooter

                                    ''''Below are other things I've tried
                                       '.leftFooter = "&#153D70" & Sheet95.Range("C3").Value gets all text
                                       '.leftFooter = "#153D70leftFooter" gets "#153D70leftFooter" in black
                                       '.leftFooter = "&#153D70leftFooter" gets the text "153D70leftFooter" in black
                                       '.leftFooter = "&#153D70" & leftFooter gets the text "153D70 valuefromRangeB3:C3 valuefromRangeB7:C7" in black
                  End With
    Next WS
Set WS = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


'Left footer Function
Function lowerleft(ByVal LfooterRange As Range) As String

'*** Sets the range of cells on the "SetupPrint" Tab as a string for the insertheaderfooter subroutine
lowerleft = ""
 If Not LfooterRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim mycell As Range
    For Each mycell In LfooterRange
        lowerleft = lowerleft & " " & mycell.Value
    Next mycell
        End If
End Function

'Right footer Function
Function lowerright(ByVal RfooterRange As Range) As String
'*** Sets the range of cells on the "SetupPrint" Tab as a string for the insertheaderfooter subroutine
lowerright = ""
 If Not RfooterRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim mycell As Range
    For Each mycell In RfooterRange
        lowerright = lowerright & " " & mycell.Value
    Next mycell
    End If
End Function
```

I continue to get simple black text and usually the VBA command prints out as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was using "&#153D70" to get the color code, based on the above link saying "&color---Prints the characters in the specified color. User supplies a hexadecimal color value." BUT APPARENTLY the correct syntax is "&K153D70" and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code snippet in one of my workbooks. I used a named range to get the value from the worksheet:

```
.CenterFooter = "&""Calibri""&8" & "Page &P" & ": " & Range("practicename").Text
```

practicename can change (I have a drop down list in the cell) and when I change it, all of the values in the sheet change, which then updates 17 pp of graphs. I needed to be able to put that practicename in the footer and that is how I did it. The first part is setting the font to Calibri, size 8 points.